# Get id of a span inside a td of a dynamic table, on click

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, onclick

I'm trying to get the id of a span created dynamically in a table. I created the table like this :

```
var initTable = function () {
$.getJSON(jsonFile, function (data) {
    var items = [];
    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
        var spanid = val.key;
        items.push(
            '<tr><td>' + val.label + '</td>'
            + '<td><span class="parameters" id="' + spanid + '">---</span> ' + val.value + '</td></tr>'
            );
        });
        $("#myTable tbody").html(items.join(""));
    });
};
```

When I click on the td, I need to get the id of the span. My query is like this :

```
$("#myTable span").click(function () {

    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(a);
});
```

It doesn't work. Someone has an idea why?

Thank you

Comment: what does your data looks like,  also try hit F12 and look at your html and check if the span does in fact have an id

Comment: Does the alert do something ? It seems that you have a typo in it that may make your code crash

Comment: try `alert(id)` and not `alert(a)`

Answer (score 1):

It my help you

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').on('click', 'span', function() {
        var spanId = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(spanId);
    });
});
```

```css
table {border: solid 1px #ccc; border-collapse: collapse;}
table td {border: solid 1px #ccc;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
 <tr>
  <td><span id="1">Span 1</span></td>
  <td><span id="2">Span 2</span></td>
  <td><span id="3">Span 3</span></td>
  <td><span id="4">Span 4</span></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

**How about this:**

i am using a revers way . i hope it will hepl full for you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('span').click(function(){
   if($(this).closest("table").attr("id") == "MyTable" )
   alert($(this).attr("id"));
});

});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>

<table id="MyTable">
<tbody>
<tr><td>Hello</td>'</tr>
<tr><td><span id ="inTable" style="cursor:pointer;">Span Inside Table</span></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<span id="outTable" style="cursor:pointer;">
  span Outside Table
</span>
```

Comment: Don't forget he is making tr dynamically, your code wouldn't work because, you are using .click

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
$("#myTable tbody tr td span").click(function () {

    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(id);
});
```

its corrected now... I was not to give whole program. It was just a hint and identification of issue that above code was facing

Comment: `a` is `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because of you are doing alert on wrong variable

`a` is `undefined` in your code

Try this

```
$(document).on('click',"#myTable span",function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try `.parameter` class in your `<span>` element ? and remember to use single quotations.

```js
$('.parameters').click(function () {
       var id = $(this).attr('id');
       alert(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="#myTable">
  <tr>
  <td>item</td>
  <td><span style="cursor:pointer" class="parameters" id="0001">---</span>Value1</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <td>item 2</td>
  <td><span style="cursor:pointer" class="parameters" id="0002">---</span>Value2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: make sure you have tr element dynamically. When you create a dynamic DOM it does not work with .click

Answer (score -1):

try .live() or on() method

```
$("#myTable span").on( "click", function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(id);
    });
```

I haven't run this code but I know this is the issue.

Comment: `a` is `undefined`

Comment: yes, corrected it. Concept in this answer was to bind dynamic elements using .on or .live.